# Can someone tell me what a List Item and List View is?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like a brief refresher course on the difference between a list item and list view is.

I believe an item is the information that goes into the list and a list view is how we display that information through the use of columns and rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A **list** is a table of a database.
- This consists of one or more **columns** (like the columns of a table in a database).
- **Items** are data from a
  list. Similar to the rows of a table in a database.
- A **list view** is a way to display the information. They may have filters, sorting and grouping among other options. They are similar to the views of the
  databases.

Comment: A list is *like* a table in the database. (In fact it is *not* a table...)

Comment: Right, it is only an analogy to facilitate explanation.